# Site master page settings page does not list all the master pages

Tags: custom-masterpage, site-settings

I have created a sub site under a parent site and when I created a master page in this sub site, It is showing up in the list in `"_catalog/Master pages"`. But when I try to change master page for this sub site in `"_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx"`, It only shows some of the master pages from parent site only. The master page file is checked in. Out of 3 master page files in drop down list, `"Customv4.master"` is not published and is Draft. The other two are Published and has been Approved. So it is not about Publishing, or approval?

Is there anything else I have to do for these master pages to be be shown in the Drop down list in `"_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx"`?

Comment: Basically check-in, publish and approve should do it. Have you set the content type to masterpage in the metadata? I've had seen it change to page layout for no reason.

Comment: Where should I change it? In "_catalog/Master pages" or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes that's the place

Comment: Got a solution to this?